# Wordpress: blank page after editing a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange problem with Wordpress (version 3.4)... If I try to edit a post I get only a blank page pointing to "wp-admin/post.php" with a HTTP 500 error and the post it's not updated. I tried to activate the debug function but I only got these messages:

```
Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2825

Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2705

Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2705
```

However they are only notice so I don't think they are related with the main error...

What I'm missing? How can I get the real error which stops the post to be edited?

Thanks!

Comment: Disable all your plugins tries again, and gives the name of the template. Please

Comment: If I disable all the plugins it seems to work, so I guess the problem is caused by one of them? With template you mean theme? In this case I'm using Arthemia Premium...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable plugins one by one and tries update your post. You will find the guilty.

Comment: Well I found the guilty but it's not a plugin that I can disable since it's vital for the blog. Any tips about how to debug it?

Comment: This is what plugin ? I advice you correct the different errors replace register_widget_control by wp_register_widget_control() to start. Find an equivalent plugin or contact author of this plugin.

Comment: @EmanueleIngrosso : If it's vital for the blog, you shouldn't have updated your WP until being sure they were compatible. You have to have a cloned testing site for this cases. Appart from zourite suggestions, I think another option is to downgrade WP, of course if you have a database backup.

Comment: Well I'm not the blog admin, in fact he just ask me for help because he didn't find the solution... plus I'm quite new in WP's world, so I was searching for some tips about debugging it effectively, because it's not very intuitive! What I don't understand is how the server can return an HTTP 500 error without a php error or warning... Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen quite a few reports of this error(err_http2_protocol_error in Wordpress ) happening on sites hosted with GoDaddy.
Copy this code and paste to your .htaccess file above     # END WordPress line

```
# BEGIN Line too long fix
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
</IfModule>
# END Line too long fix
```